# Count multiple fields in one SQL view?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have 4 different schema that are stored on table A and I want to create a SQL view that shows the total count of customers interested in each destination/field. The schema values for each destination are Y so how can I make something that looks like this where it would total all the cases where Mexico = Y?

| Destination | TotalCustomersInterested |
| --- | --- |
| Mexico | total # |
| Aruba | total # |
| DR | total # |
| Hawaii | total # |

Comment: What have you tried?  this seems to be a simple `select field, count(CustomerIDentifier) from table group by field`  and maybe count(distinct identifier)  on the customer identifer if you allow duplicates in the data for a destination/customer

Comment: you need to edit your question and show a [mcve] with the sample data

Comment: Your table has _columns_. not fields.